# Javascript Custom prompt box help needed

Tags: javascript, return, dom-events, custom-controls, prompt

I have made a custom prompt box for Javascript so I don't have to use the stock ones, however I cannot figure out how to return the value from the directly from the `cPrompt()` function. I want to be able to use it like a normal prompt and be able to do stuff like `var name = cPrompt("Whats your name")` however to close the custom prompt I must use an event to trigger a function called `ok()` when a button is clicked. This inhibits me from returning the value directly from the `cPrompt` function. Can anyone figure out how I can do this? Here is my code:

HTML:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Custom Prompt</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>content</p>
    <button onclick="cPrompt('Message goes here')">Click me</button>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="pBox">
        <div id="cPromptOut" onclick="ok()"></div>
        <input type="text" id="cPromptIn"/>
    </div>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='customPrompt.css'/>
    <script src='customPrompt.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#overlay{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:grey;
    opacity:0.5;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
#pBox{
    width:50%;
    height:30%;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:red;
    left:25%;
    top:20%;
    z-index: 11;
    display:none;
}
#cPromptOut{
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 12;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em
}
#cPromptIn{
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em
}
```

JS:

```
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay")
var pBox = document.getElementById("pBox")
var cPromptOut = document.getElementById("cPromptOut")
var In = document.getElementById("cPromptIn").value
function cPrompt(msg){
    
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    pBox.style.display = "block";
    cPromptOut.innerHTML = msg;

}
function ok(){
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    pBox.style.display = "none";
}

console.log(cPrompt("enter you name"))
```

So right now I'm not able to collect the value in the box. Can anyone figure out how I can do this? Remember I want to be able to call it just like a prompt without having to use any other calls like `console.log(cPrompt("say something"))`. I might be trying to over-think this or maybe its impossible, any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - ok so it won't be as simple as console.log(cPrompt('message')), but there is a *kinda* way to go about doing what you want. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ybq5e/20/) adapted from [toby Ho's trampolines](http://tobyho.com/2010/12/10/trampolines-in-javascript-and/). I can't make it work in chrome for some reason, but firefox does the trick. the cool part is in main() (it will have to be inside a `run(main())` call

```
function main(){
    log('start listening');
    log(yield prompt('hello'));//the code "seems" to halt here.
    log('end script');
}
```

Again you're asking something quite hard so it won't be as easy as you would like it to be, but here it is. Also, it would've been cool to tell us what you had tried so far.

BEFORE EDIT :

At first glance I would say it is impossible. if your `cPrompt()` function holds the interpreter so it can return the user's input, I think th page will freeze. have you tried something like this?

```
//This will probably freeze the page
function cPrompt(_msg){
    ...//init the prompt
    while( input == null){}//your prompt sets input in an event
    return input;
}
```

The usual way to go about it is to pass a closure like this

```
function whenInput(_input){console.log(_input);}
cPrompt('message', whenInput);
```

Now, I'm thinking that there may be a way with the new [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Generators) in js 1.7.

So, what have you tried?

Comment: The first method you have with the while loop doea not work as it either returns too early or causes a too much recursion error, and i have never see the second example could you explain what it is and what _input means ?

Comment: as I said, the first bit of code will freeze the page.

the second is common, but it will not achieve what you want. here you can learn more about closures https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: ok, so your question intrigued me, and it turns out there may be a way, via "trampolines" : http://tobyho.com/2010/12/10/trampolines-in-javascript-and/. Be aware that it is quite mind-wrapping. I made a fiddle with a good start, but I can't return the value in the end : http://jsfiddle.net/Ybq5e/10/

Comment: well its easy enough to do without returning the variable, but i want it to act like the normal prompt() function and not have to save the result to another variable

Comment: I've researched further, it is possible with `console.log(yield cPrompt('what ya gonna do?'));` see my edit.